# how to update database sequentially using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a long list from database which i want to update a field by name group. i want to update the first 30 to value '1' next 30 to value '2' and so on until the end

Any idea on how to go about it

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,
   "UPDATE `tablename` SET `group` = '$value' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tablename ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0, 30)");
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: what is the result of your query?

Comment: I think you should try with `Stored Procedures`

Comment: @tamil, stored procedures can definitely do this trick but it's probably over kill.

Comment: the second answer went well. but i had to repeat the process. i believe there has to be a php code with for i loop. or a do while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your update is a one-time thing (and don't need to optimize it, e.g. do it all in one query), you can simply repeat the following query until you are finished:

```
update `tablename` 
SET `group` = '$value' 
where `group` is null
order by id desc
limit 30;
```

All group-values have to be null (or some other unused value) to begin with, so e.g. use `update tablename SET group = null` first, if they aren't.

And you probably want to do it all in a transaction.

Comment: come to think of it, this is a better answer than mine +1

Answer (score 3):

You have run into this limitation of [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

> You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a
>   subquery.

You could use an update join, but since limits are involved, you would once again run into the same issue. Since only a small number of records are involved, you could do a simple query to get the ids.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM tablename ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0, 30
```

Then use that in the next query

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `group` = '$value' WHERE id IN (ids_from_above_query)
```

If you are worried about concurrent updates, start a transaction.