# MySQL Conditional Update in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, conditional-statements

I'm looking for a simple way to do an update on a table only if there is no other columns present in that same table with the same value I'm trying to update, ideally in a single query. So far I'm getting an error `You specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause`. Here is what I tried in a few variations so far (still unable to get working):

```
UPDATE emailQueue AS t1 
SET 
    t1.lockedOn = 1470053240
WHERE
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            emailQueue AS t2
        WHERE
            t2.lockedOn = 1470053240) = 0
        AND t1.lockedOn IS NULL
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update database sequentially using mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693492/how-to-update-database-sequentially-using-mysql)

Comment: @e4c5 seriously there is no way around this?

Comment: You have to use a join as mentioned in that question and as posted by @Gordon-linoff as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you need to use a `join`.  In this case, a `left join` is in order:

```
UPDATE emailQueue eq LEFT JOIN
       emailQueue eq2
       ON eq2.lockedOn = 1470053240
    SET eq.lockedOn = 1470053240
WHERE eq.lockedOn IS NULL AND
      eq2.lockedOn IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly how this works but it works somehow. More explanation in the answer could be useful :)